# Firebase Cloud Messaging AppDelegate Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is code in the Firebase Docs.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
            authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
```

I didn't modified any line of code. But Xcode says "Use of undeclared type `UNAuthorizationOptions`, `UNUserNotificationCenter`, `FIRMessagingDelegate`"

and I have one more line.

```
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,object: nil)
```

It says "Value of Type AppDelegate has no member `tokenRefreshNotification`"

I just copied and pasted my code from firebase docs but there is error!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The example in Firebase docs is outdated. Here is the code for most recent Xcode 9 and Swift 3:

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        FIRApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
             Messaging.messaging().delegate = self                
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }
}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

    }

}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I must use Xcode 8? When I import UserNotifications in Xcode 7.3.1 I get error: No such module 'UserNotifications'...

Comment: means no chance to support ios 7 and earlier ?

Comment: And how Do I subscribe to a Topic? Using : [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/news"] gives me an error: expected "," separator.

Comment: Did you  @import Firebase;   ?

Comment: II tried that but when I send test notification I don't get any sound with the notification.. do you know why?

Comment: Do you send the notification from console or through API? If you are using console, make sure your message has highest priority and all other relevant attributes (can be configured in the "send notification" form).

Comment: I am trying to set the remoteMessageDelegate in objective c but it doesn't exist, kindly what is the alternative code for objective c?

Answer (score 12):

Don't forget to

import FirebaseMessaging

import UserNotifications

```js
//
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc.
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
// running iOS 10 and above. Implement FIRMessagingDelegate to receive data message via FCM for
// devices running iOS 10 and above.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end
#endif

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  // Register for remote notifications
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
  } else {
    // iOS 8 or later
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
      UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
      (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
      UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
      [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
      // iOS 10 or later
      #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
      UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
          UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
          | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
          | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
          requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          }
       ];

      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
      // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
      [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
      #endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]
  }

  // [START configure_firebase]
  [FIRApp configure];
  // [END configure_firebase]
  // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                               name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
  return YES;
}

// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // Print message ID.
  NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // Print message ID.
  NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
  // Print message ID.
  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
  NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
  // Print full message
  NSLog(@"%@", [remoteMessage appData]);
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
  // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
  // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
  // should be done.
  NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
  NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

  // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
  [self connectToFcm];

  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
  }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

  // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
  // [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [self connectToFcm];
}

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
  NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]

@end
```

Comment: hello. can u explain why need to disconnect firebase when appdidenterbackground? Then can i got message when app in background?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the following imports to your file:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
```

You also need a method named `tokenRefreshNotification` similar to the following:

```
func tokenRefreshNotification() {
    let fcmDeviceToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    // TODO: Send token to server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 2.0
add the FIRMessagingDelegate protocol

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate{}
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.3 version of Alexey’s answer would be:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in})

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert , .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

And..

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

    }

}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```